# Vertical scrollbar won't appear on div even though content overflows?

Tags: html, css

```css
.calHeadDay,
.calBodyDay {
  width: calc((100% - 60px)/7);
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #4567b1;
  color: #4567b1;
}

.calHeadTime,
.calBodyTime {
  width: 60px;
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calHeadDay {
  background-color: #eaf2f5;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 3px;
}

.calHeader,
.calBody {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.calBody {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.calTimeBlock {
  border: 1px solid #d5d8dd;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: right;
  color: #556;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.calTimeBlock+.calTimeBlock {
  border-top: none;
}


}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="calHeader">
    <div class="calHeadTime"></div>
    <div class="calHeadDay">
      <!-- react-text: 15 -->Sunday
      <!-- /react-text --><br>
      <!-- react-text: 17 -->Aug 13, 2017
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
    <div class="calHeadDay">
      <!-- react-text: 19 -->Monday
      <!-- /react-text --><br>
      <!-- react-text: 21 -->Aug 14, 2017
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
    <div class="calHeadDay">
      <!-- react-text: 23 -->Tuesday
      <!-- /react-text --><br>
      <!-- react-text: 25 -->Aug 15, 2017
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
    <div class="calHeadDay">
      <!-- react-text: 27 -->Wednesday
      <!-- /react-text --><br>
      <!-- react-text: 29 -->Aug 16, 2017
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
    <div class="calHeadDay">
      <!-- react-text: 31 -->Thursday
      <!-- /react-text --><br>
      <!-- react-text: 33 -->Aug 17, 2017
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
    <div class="calHeadDay">
      <!-- react-text: 35 -->Friday
      <!-- /react-text --><br>
      <!-- react-text: 37 -->Aug 18, 2017
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
    <div class="calHeadDay">
      <!-- react-text: 39 -->Saturday
      <!-- /react-text --><br>
      <!-- react-text: 41 -->Aug 19, 2017
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="calBody">
    <div class="calBodyTime">
      <div class="calTimeBlock">7am</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">8am</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">9am</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">10am</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">11am</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">12pm</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">1pm</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">2pm</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">3pm</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">4pm</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">5pm</div>
      <div class="calTimeBlock">6pm</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calBodyDay"></div>
    <div class="calBodyDay"></div>
    <div class="calBodyDay"></div>
    <div class="calBodyDay"></div>
    <div class="calBodyDay"></div>
    <div class="calBodyDay"></div>
    <div class="calBodyDay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've set the `max-height` of `.calBody` to 500px, but the content takes up 600px. Why isn't a scrollbar appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only modify the some classes as blow:

```
.calHeader,
.calBody {
  /*display: table;*/
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

But the scroll bar in the right side of page causes that the header and body of columns are not same width.

Comment: It also de-collapses my borders and makes the column dividers not stretch all the way down when scrolled. Will have to fiddle with this, thanks.

Comment: I think if you put some contents in columns they will stretch all the way down. But I didn't understand what are you meaning of de-collapsing the borders.

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse` doesn't work on non-tables. The borders are thicker now. I can work around that too though.

Comment: `flex` ended up working out better than wrapping the body in an extra block. Can use `flex: 1` on the columns instead of trying to calculate their width. It also doesn't shift around when I add stuff into the columns. Good stuff!

Comment: Yes `flex` has some advantages and is the trend method for make a good layout for a webpage. The good UI frameworks like Bootstrap are migrating to flex based layout too. Goodluck

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can get a scroll bar on an element with `display: table`. You can wrap the `.calBody` inside another div and apply the max height and overflow settings to that div instead.

```
<div class="bodyWrapper">

<div class="calBody">
<div class="calBodyTime">
  <div class="calTimeBlock">7am</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">8am</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">9am</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">10am</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">11am</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">12pm</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">1pm</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">2pm</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">3pm</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">4pm</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">5pm</div>
  <div class="calTimeBlock">6pm</div>
</div>
<div class="calBodyDay"></div>
<div class="calBodyDay"></div>
<div class="calBodyDay"></div>
<div class="calBodyDay"></div>
<div class="calBodyDay"></div>
<div class="calBodyDay"></div>
<div class="calBodyDay"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Then set the css:

```
.bodyWrapper{
  display:block;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but try setting the overflow to auto using `overflow: auto;` that sets it to scroll when it overflows and not to scroll when it doesn't.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. `height` instead of `max-height` doesn't work either, nor does adding `!important`.